# How to add several lines to file with Puppet

Tags: puppet

I did not find any elegant way to add several lines to an existing file.

I noticed the [Simple Text Patterns](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/simple_text_patterns) wiki page, but I have to add a block into `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Any clue?

Comment: augeas is the normal way

Comment: thx. I will give it a try

Comment: As a note, the question has been flaged to be closed by two people already. You might want to rephrase it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that augeas is by far the best answer to what you are trying.

I would also recommend the [`file_line`](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/file_line.rb) resource from the [stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) puppet library. It tends to be much more lightweight than augeas.

You would have to define one resource for each line, and if the order is important you can add dependencies between the invocations.

Sample usage:

```
        file_line { "no_ipv6_networking":
            path  => "/etc/sysconfig/network",
            line  => "NETWORKING_IPV6=no",
            match => "^NETWORKING_IPV6=",
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You coud use the [`augeas`](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/puppet_augeas) type for this, but the ideal solution would be to use [`netcf`](https://fedorahosted.org/netcf/) since you want to manage network interfaces.

Some time ago, I have started a [Puppet Netcf provider](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-netcf). It is still *not ready for production*, but if you have some Ruby skills, it's probably the best solution for your need (and PRs are most definitely welcome, too).

The Netcf provider takes an XML interface definition as input, for example:

```
netcf_if {"eth1":
  ensure     => up,
  definition => '
<interface type="ethernet" name="eth1">
  <start mode="onboot"/>
  <protocol family="ipv4">
    <ip address="192.168.0.5" prefix="24"/>
    <route gateway="192.168.0.1"/>
  </protocol>
</interface>
';
}
```

You can find more examples of XML definitions in [the Netcf repository](http://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/netcf.git/tree/tests/interface).